# npm ERR! Object.entries is not a function

Tags: npm

My project show this error when i try to run npm install for any package:

```
npm ERR! Object.entries is not a function
```

someone with same error?

Comment: provide more details...what command you are running

Comment: Hi Swan, the issue was solved, but the details of the command just be: "npm install --save query" for example. When i updated npm to the latest version all worked fine. tks for your help :)

Answer (score 12):

Updating npm to latest version (6.0.1) resolves this issue.

It's been reported here:
https://github.com/npm/npm-audit-report/issues/9

Comment: Tks!! Worked here

Answer (score 7):

The same error occurred.
There is a possibility of bug of npm 6.0.0.
Downgrading to npm 5.8.0 no longer causes errors.