# Upgrading nativescript to 4.1.0

Tags: nativescript

At the time of writing, nativescript version on npm is `4.0.2`, but on github, there is a tag for `4.1.0`. I would like to install `4.1.0`, since some bugs have been fixed there.

`tns update 4.1.0` returns `Could not update the project!` error and `npm install -g nativescript@4.1.0` returns `No matching version found` error.

How can I upgrade?

Comment: `npm install -g nativescript@next` did install latest `4.2.0`, but I would still like to know how to install `4.1.0`.

Comment: Added screenshot to update to 4.1.0 RC

Comment: 4.1.0 is coming out this week so stay tuned. Then you will be able to upgrade to the official packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to latest version using

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

Can also follow the [Instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript

**UPDATE**
You cannot update to 4.1.0 since there is no version on it.

You can however use the following to upgrade / update to the RC

```
npm install -g nativescript@4.1.0-2018-05-25-11664
```

[Screenshot for above](http://prntscr.com/jnjabp)

If that fails

Try updating npm then do the above

This might be caused by [npm-audit-report](https://github.com/npm/npm-audit-report/issues/9)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50269601/4712391)

Comment: Doesn't help. Missed `-g` in my question, sorry, but I tried that already.

Comment: What version of npm are you runnnng?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about such list of versions on npm.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This can be very much bleeding edge.   But let me help you navigate it...

NativeScript has several packages that are intertwined.

1. The CLI (npm i -g nativescript)
2. The Core Modules (npm i tns-core-modules --save)
3. The runtimes android or ios (tns platform add ios)

The newer runtimes may depend on features in the core modules; so you might have to make sure you have an updated core modules if you update your runtimes.  This isn't always needed; I frequently test out only one of the three things at a time; but occasionally you need to update everything to make it work.

---

**The simple instructions:**

```
npm i -g nativescript@rc
npm i tns-core-modules@rc --save
tns platform remove android 
tns platform add android@rc 
tns platform remove ios
tns platform add ios@rc
```

---

**The informative instructions:**

The CLI can be very dependent on which version of the runtimes you plan on using.  For example the current 4.x cli can't work with the older 2.x projects anymore.   However, it does continue to work with recent 3.x projects.  And vise-versa; The 2.x CLI won't build 4.x projects correctly.   So you are much safer using the same major version of the CLI as the runtimes you plan on using.   (Normally you use the latest release runtimes; but if you have existing projects that haven't been upgraded you might still have 2.x projects)

---

NativeScript has three version tags depending on what you want.

1. The standard @LATEST, public version (i.e. `npm i -g nativescript@latest` ) will give you the current latest **release** version.  Typically a `npm i -g nativescript` is equivalent to @latest; but in cases of core modules it will use the version in the package.json file.  So if you want to install the latest release; it is safer to tack on the `@latest` to make sure you get the latest release.
2. The @NEXT version; this is actually a LIE.   **NEXT = Master**; this is NOT the NEXT version of NativeScript.   This means you will have everything that has been accepted to master including things that might not actually be rolled out for several more versions (or ever).  Master can and typically is buggy, some days more than others.   Next versions are generated nightly.  But it is very useful for testing if a fix works; DO NOT release an app to clients on @next; you will most likely regret it.
3. The @RC version; this is actually the release candidate.  This version shows up typically a week or so before the final release of the next public version.   This is normally a fairly safe version to use; these are manually generated releases for them to start doing in-depth testing before the release version.  Please note; that once 4.1 is released the RC is going to point to the 4.1 RC; which is older than latest -- not the final release.  So you only want to use @RC when it actually points to a newer version than @latest.

---

**Updating NativeScript CLI:**
So now to tell what is the current versions you can do:
`npm info nativescript` and as of today you would see:

```
  'dist-tags':
   { latest: '4.0.2',
     next: '4.2.0-2018-05-30-11723',
     rc: '4.1.0-2018-05-30-11720' },
```

Notice that @latest = `4.02`, @next = `4.2.x-DATE` and @rc = `4.1.x-DATE`.

In this case; doing `npm i -g nativescript@next` will give you the current Master 4.2.x  However, since you are wanting 4.1 and preferably a stable version; since RC has been updated to 4.1 already; then your best bet is to do:
`npm i -g nativescript@rc --save` and you will get 4.1.0 of the CLI.

Now to update your project;

**Updating Core Modules:**
You would want to do `npm info tns-core-modules` again to see the tags for the core modules and you would see something like

```
'dist-tags':
   { latest: '4.0.1',
     next: '4.2.0-2018-05-30-01',
     rc: '4.1.0-2018-05-30-06' },
```

So just like the CLI you would use `npm i tns-core-modules@rc`; please note no `-g` as this is a package that is installed as part of your app.

**Updating the Android Runtimes**
Do `npm info tns-android`

```
  'dist-tags':
   { latest: '4.0.1',
     next: '4.2.0-2018-05-30-01',
     rc: '4.1.1-rc-2018-05-28-03' },
```

For the platforms you need to remove the older version; then install the newer version.

`tns platform remove android` and then `tns platform add android@rc`

**Updating the iOS Runtimes**
Do `npm info tns-ios`

```
  'dist-tags':
   { latest: '4.0.1',
     next: '4.1.0-2018-05-25-01',
     rc: '4.1.0-rc-2018-05-26-01' },
```

And then type
`tns platform remove ios` and then `tns platform add ios@rc`

---

Final notes:

- Very frequently you can get away with upgrading just the runtimes or core modules without updating anything else.  However, if you have issues building or the app crashes on startup; then you probably need to update everything to be in sync.
- You can do `npm i -g nativescript@4.1.0-2018-05-30-11720` to install a specific version of it.  However, in the many years I've done this I can't think of a reason I have had to do anything beyond the tags of @latest, @next or @rc.
- Remember there are THREE separate pieces that you need to be aware of; the CLI (which builds the app; but really has no effect on bugs in the app).  The Runtimes (i.e. the JavaScript engine that runs your code), and the Core modules (i.e. the code that makes `<Label>` become the proper text display on each platform.   Depending on which layer your issue is in; that is the piece you want to upgrade.
- If you are using NativeScript-Angular, NativeScript-Vue, or the NativeScript-Webpack; there are additional pieces you may have to install to make them compatible with a @rc or @next version.

Comment: `npm info tns-core-modules --save` no ? ( with save flag) , would be lovely if you can update this answer as 4.1 is official :)

Comment: (I would also suggest webpack update since it has change...)